# How to create web service on netbeans?

Tags: java, web-services, netbeans, glassfish

I am trying to deploy my class project as web service on glassfish. I was told that this is really simple and netbeans does all the work and even creates the WSDL for you. I see where you can make a webservice client. But where do you go to make the webservice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an [Axis tutorial](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/gs-axis.html#java_project), and here's a [JAX-WS](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/jax-ws.html) one. If you're looking for REST, then follow [this one](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/rest.html).
And here's the [general link](http://netbeans.org/kb/trails/web.html) to Web Services in NetBeans.